# How can I get the namespace from a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, namespaces

I have a method that I specify to be of a certain type.

E.g.

```
public MyLabels GetLabels<T>()
{
    // I'd like to get the namespace of the type that T represents here
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `typeof(T).FullName`.

That string contains both the class name and the namespace.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `Namespace` property of `Type`:

```
typeof(T).Namespace
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.namespace.aspx)

Comment: The linked documentation is interesting to say the least.  The last two of these three sentences seem to contradict each other directly: "If the current Type represents a constructed generic type, this property returns the namespace that contains the generic type definition.  Similarly, if the current Type represents a generic parameter T, this property returns the namespace that contains the generic type definition that defines T.  If the current Type object represents a generic parameter, this property returns null"

Comment: @phoog. I believe it's talking about `public class Foo<T>`, at this point `T` wasn't resolved.

Comment: Right, but the first sentence says, for example, that for the `T` in `IEnumerable<T>` the property would return `"System.Collections.Generic"`, while the second sentence says that it would return `null`.

Comment: @phoog. Yep it doesn't make too much sense... :( But as long as we know how to use it... I don't care.

Answer (score 6):

```
typeof(T).FullName // namespace and class name 
typeof(T).Namespace // namespace, no class name
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
typeof(T).Namespace;
```